# Сотовая связь. В частном доме, как ее улучшить?

Tags: связь

Живу в частном доме где то около окраины города(после нас есть еще район) и тут с сотовой связью все ну не очень. Я по изучал по этой теме и если честно фигню советуют... я просто хочу стабильный интернет вечером, а они мне советуют покупать что то за 100к плюс. И да местные мегалайны отказываются проводить мне интернет или просят за это очень много. Так вот из статьёй по инету я думаю установить антенну в сторону хорошей соты, кстати рядом со мной их 5 и ко всем около 100mdb и решил также по экспериментировать и установить кабель напрямую к алюминиевой крыше. Трабла антенны в том что она только на одно устройство (вроде как) и только в одном положении... Кстати дома еще есть свободная спутниковая тарелка, но приконтачив ее кабель и антенну телефона мне дало лишь +-10 mdb, да и неудобно это. Так вот есть ли тут какие-нибудь гуманные решения, а не плавления металла по форме телефона. Или мне придётся тратить 300к на проводку?

Comment: роутер с симкой и внешняя антенна

Comment: Без выезда специалиста с оборудованием такие вопросы не решаются.

Comment: Если хотите попробовать решить вопрос самостоятельно https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=460625

Comment: https://mikrotik.com/product/lhg_lte_kit сейчас модно

Answer (score 1):

Я советую приобрести Вам USB модем с сим картой и возможностью раздавать wi-fi и с разъемом для внешней антенны (4G 3G USB Wi-Fi модем FDD LTE 4G Wi-Fi роутер беспроводной FDD-LTE FDD B1(2100)/B3(1800) МГц - это для пример для поиска). То что есть спутниковая тарелка, это отлично, с ней можно хорошо потестировать направление лучшего сигнала. Но перед покупкой изучите тему band на какой частоте работает ближайшая сотовая вышка и предоставляет ли оператор нужную вам частоту (например 1800 МГц это Band3). Если вы находитесь в Беларуси, то вот тут (https://becloud.by/customers/ob-lte-advanced/#) можно посмотреть карту и информацию о вышках и частотах.
Если после этого скорость интернета Вас еще не устраивает, то можете самостоятельно изготовить антенну. Они существуют разных типов, но по моему мнению самые простые в изготовлении в кустарных условиях это:

- антенна Харченко (биквадрат), её преимущество на коротких расстояниях хороший стабильный сигнал, но она далеко не ловит, но со спутниковой можно попробовать.
- антенна Yagi (иногда называют 3-4G пушка), её преимущество на длинных расстояниях до вышки (25км может дотянуть, а то и больше, в зависимости от рельефа, преград, строений), она немного прихотлива в точной сборке расстояния между дисками и радиусе этих дисков. И еще один минус, кому то может не значительный, это ping, если вышка очень далеко, то пинг может "прыгать" до 100ms, видосы смотреть не проблема, а вот в онлайн шутерах будут задержки.

Фото антенны Yagi и название приложения где можно выбрать разновидность антенны и задать нужную частоту.
[image: Yagi]

PS: если будут вопросы, задавайте, помогу чем смогу :)